# Facebook iOS 3.1 SDK: can login with Safari but not natively

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm integrating the iOS 3.1 Facebook SDK. When implementing a login with Facebook feature, I call `FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:`. When called on the simulator (where I don't have a FB account set up natively) I can successfully login.

However, from a device with a native Facebook account setup, when calling `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions...` the session type returned in the completion handler is always `sessionStateClosedLoginFailed`, regardless of whether I allow or disallow my app to use Facebook in the alert dialog. The session state before calling the method is `sessionStateCreated`.

This is the `NSError` from the completion handler:
`Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x20a80820 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x208ed930 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}}`

What am I doing wrong that would cause this problem?

*Update*: I just noticed that my app is not appearing in the Settings > Facebook > "Allow these apps to use your account' section. (It was definitely there earlier today).

*Update2*: If I delete my account from the iOS Settings app, and then log my test user into the Facebook iPhone app, I am able to login with fast app switching. So it appears to only be a problem with the native account.

*Update3*: I ran the sample Facebook app Scrumptious I have the same problem. Upon clicking 'Login', which calls the `openActiveSessionWithRead...` I get the same error.

*Update4*: Possibly related to this bug? http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/450137751688028?browse=search_50a43a39b37ae4868318658

*Update5*: I should have mentioned this earlier, but it was a Facebook test user account that had this problem.

Comment: This title is wrapped into 3 lines when viewed on the main page. Perhaps you should consider rephrasing and reformatting the post.

Comment: Sorry; my writing is pretty bad in the post; good call to change it. I made the title more concise and rephrased the post a little.

Comment: Have you tried removing the app from the device by long pressing and hitting X, and then re-installing. I have found that when debugging FB SDK issues, stale data can get cached.

Comment: Yes. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the app several times but still have the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched from using a Facebook test user account to a regular account and this solved the problem on both the Scrumptious app and my app.

Comment: thanks for this. would not have wasted an entire afternoon if i had seen this earlier.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you mind clarifying by "Facebook test user account" to "regular account"?  Is this something you did with sandbox mode or is this another setting that you have to change?

Comment: Facebook has a feature where you can make 'test users'. From my logged in account on Facebook.com, I chose my app on the sidebar, scrolled down to the 'roles' section, clicked 'edit roles', and from here I can create test accounts, which are Facebook accounts with their own email/password. I believe they're unrelated to sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `FacebookAppID` in your plist? See "Adding your Facebook App ID" in section 5 of the [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/). Also, check the "Facebook" section of your device's settings to make sure your app hasn't been unauthorized (in which case it won't be authorized unless you manually do so).

Comment: Yes, the FacebookAppID is in the .plist, and matches the one on the Facebook app settings page and the one in the URL scheme (sans the 'fb' prefix)

Comment: Hmm. Then all I can suggest is double checking the spelling and capitalization of the app id key name and value in the plist, and confirm all of the other settings in that _Getting Started_ doc. Sorry I don't have any other suggestions. Hopefully someone else has some suggestions! Is your app showing up in the Facebook section of the Settings app?

Comment: Rob, good call; my app isn't showing up the Facebook section of Settings. I'm not sure why that would be -- it was there earlier today.

Comment: The bundle identifier is definitely the same as the one on Facebook.