# Trouble getting Facebook login and permission request will occur natively in iOS 6 and not fast-app-switch

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, ios6, parse-platform

I am having issues getting the permission request and login to happen natively in iOS, and am currently always getting the fast-app-switch where the authentication happens in a Safari window before switching back to iOS.  I have ensured that I logged into Facebook using the Settings app in iPhone Simulator, as well as that I am only requesting **read**, and not both read and write permissions (in fact my permission array is empty, thus only getting a user's public profile and friend list).

I am using Parse API's `PFFacebookUtils`, which according to their [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html#//api/name/logInWithPermissions%3ablock%3a) delegates to the Facebook SDK to authenticate the user.

Here is my code log in code:

```
- (IBAction)logInFacebook:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[];

    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

        if (!user){
            if(!error){
                NSLog(@"User cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error occured: %@", error);
            }
        } else if (user.isNew){
            NSLog(@"User with facebook just signed up and logged in.");
            //Code to move to a new view.  Not shown for breveity
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook already logged in.");
            //Move to new view
        }
    }];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

My question is - is my code causing the old fast-app-switch view to happen, or is some settings in iPhone simulator not done correctly?  Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried to run this on the phone.  I have to double check but i think in the simulator it will always open safari to login and on the phone it will login natively

Comment: Thanks Yan - I saw the comments here that alluded to the fact that it was a setting in iPhone simulator.  However, I didn't understand what they were specifically referring to.  I will try it on my phone though.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387798/facebook-ios-3-1-sdk-can-login-with-safari-but-not-natively/13390757#comment26614836_13390757