# openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions does not login with ios6 native login

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-login

I am using Facebook SDK 3.7.1. 
I am trying to login using openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions, but it always direct me to safari, even when I have the native login account setup.

here's what i have done:

1,on the plist, I set the FacebookAppID, the FacebookDisplayName, and the URL Schemes as suggested.

2,on the facebook account, I set up the BundleID, and enable Facebook Login under Native iOS app.

3, I am not loggin in as a test user, [Facebook iOS 3.1 SDK: can login with Safari but not natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387798/facebook-ios-3-1-sdk-can-login-with-safari-but-not-natively)

Can anyone give me some suggestions where goes wrong?